# Add Azure group member from on perm AD powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a Powershell script that runs every day on our on perm AD and making few actions for new employees.
I'm trying also to add those users to one of our Azure AD groups (Add-AzureADGroupMember) but currently bo luck when trying to get the  ObjectId.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-module AzureAD

$tenantId = "1516515611561651651"
$azureUser = "my@mail.com"
$AzureCredential = Get-Content "Encrypted.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (1..16)
$AzureCred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $AzureUser, $AzureCredential
$SearchBase = "OU=ou,DC=DC,DC=my"

Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties extensionAttribute1, mail, extensionAttribute12, userPrincipalName -Filter * | ForEach-Object {
          # Connect to Azure AD
          Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $azureUser -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $AzureCred
          $objid= Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$_.userPrincipalName'" | select ObjectId
          Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 6546fewf4s894f98sdfsd4f -RefObjectId $objid
}
```

Comment: `Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $_.UserPrincipalName` will be easier syntax rather than filtering. You should also probably use `select -expand ObjectId` instead to retrieve only the `ObjectId` value. Personally, I would move the `Connect-AzureAD` command outside of the loop so that you aren't attempting to reconnect every time for each queried user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Get-AzureADUser` parameter `ObjectId` accepts a UPN value, you can simplify your syntax and remove the filtering. You also only need to connect to AzureAD once rather than for each user. Using `-Expand` or `-ExpandProperty` on [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1) retrieves only the value of that property rather than an object that contains the property. [Add-AzureAdGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) parameter `-RefObjId` expects a string that contains only an objectID value.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-module AzureAD

$tenantId = "1516515611561651651"
$azureUser = "my@mail.com"
$AzureCredential = Get-Content "Encrypted.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (1..16)
$AzureCred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $AzureUser, $AzureCredential
$SearchBase = "OU=ou,DC=DC,DC=my"

# Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $azureUser -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $AzureCred

Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties extensionAttribute1, mail, extensionAttribute12, userPrincipalName -Filter * | ForEach-Object {
          $objid = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.userPrincipalName | Select -Expand ObjectId
          Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 6546fewf4s894f98sdfsd4f -RefObjectId $objid
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful and all is working now as expected. Regarding the command in the loop, was an emberesing mistake from my side :-). Thanks!!